# remove erroneous values from array

Tags: filtering, image

I have a set of squares arrays (images) of values -100k to 100k. Occasionally the camera that generates the images has a readout error and reads an extremely high value (in the 10e30 range). These are background subtracted images (hence the negative to positive range) and the values can also be -10e30.

I'm trying to come up with a function that would identify these and replace with the mean of 4/9 surrounding pixels.

I'd be happy to provide a file but pastebin does not allow as the file size is about 2 MB.

Comment: Two problems with your approach - 1) how to handle the padding at the edges of the image, and 2) what to do if there are two large values next to each other? The averaging might not get rid of the large distortions in this case. You could probably use the Min or Median to more robustly remove them for 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using `Padding->None` since no padding was specified. This leads to a smaller image so you lose the outermost pixels. I've also used `Median` instead of `Mean` because `Mean` will not behave as well when two large values appear next to each other:

```
(* You could use ImageData[yourimage] here, assuming 1-channel *)
testimg = {
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
  {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}, 
  {17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24},
  {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, -10^96, 31, 32}, 
  {33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40},
  {41, 42, 10^60, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48}, 
  {49, 50, 51, 10^90, 53, 54, 55, 56},
  {57, 58, 10^54, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64}};

r = 1;
ArrayFilter[
  With[{f = Flatten@#, c = #[[r + 1, r + 1]]}, 
    If[Abs[c] < 10^30, c, Median[f]]] &,
  testimg, r, Padding -> None
  ] // N
```

```
{{10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15.},
 {18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23.},
 {26., 27., 28., 29., 29., 31.},
 {34., 35., 36., 37., 38., 39.},
 {42., 44., 44., 45., 46., 47.},
 {50., 51., 60., 53., 54., 55.}}
```

Comment: This seems to be doing the job perfectly well. Thanks.